# how to find the total number of rows in a class/table in Parse (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I know how to count total number of rows in a PFOjbect class for IOS like:

```
int count = [query countObjects];
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do it incase of JS.
How could I do that?

Comment: var count = countObjects.length;

Comment: that would give me only selected rows from my query which is maximum 1000.But I have a lot more data than that.I have to find out the total number of rows in a table/class.

Comment: I thought Parse.com was finished?

Comment: Not yet.But they will shutdown next year.However,they have made their sdk public and one can host it as they need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Didn't realise it works for 1000+ rows too.@T.Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-counting-objects):

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Sean Plott");
query.count({
  success: function(count) {
    // The count request succeeded. Show the count
    alert("Sean has played " + count + " games");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // The request failed
  }
});
```